# How to create data model for Spring boot having multiple parent and child combinations

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to create data model for Spring boot having multiple parent and child combinations with JPA repository to store data to mysql

```
{"messages": [{"to":"+123","hsm":{"template": "demo","parameters":{"1": "12-12-2018"}}}]}
```

Comment: please explain in details.

Comment: Are you asking for data model to represent the above json data?

Comment: Should i use ManyToMany relation in this case ?
I want all the data to be persisted in 1 table, i dont know if thats possible, pretty new to spring boot

Comment: Why do you want to use a relational database and persist everything in one table? You could use MongoDB that would maybe better fit your needs

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, i read about  @OneToMany relations but both have different data models and create different database tables.
Not sure how to join them